# SQL Join Missing Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables. Both have the same column names, one is a template ([BaseDipline]) and the other is a table populated with real data ([vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary]). I want to join them so that the Qty on the template table matches the Qty on the real table.

Template table:

| Packing Station | PackDate | Shift | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 0 |
| Dip Line 2 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Dip Line 2 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 2 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 0 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 0 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 0 |

Table with real data:

| Packing Station | PackDate | Shift | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 1180 |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 555 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 762 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 1005 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 1792 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 704 |

Below is my code.

```
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(100)=CONVERT(varchar,getdate(),110)

SELECT 
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[BaseDipline].PackingStation, 
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary].PackDate,
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[BaseDipline].[Shift],
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary].Qty
FROM
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[BaseDipline]
INNER JOIN 
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary] 
         ON [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[BaseDipline].PackingStation = [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary].PackingStation
         AND [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[BaseDipline].[Shift] = [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary].[Shift]
WHERE 
    [MKE_PSS].[dbo].[vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary].PackDate = @Date
ORDER BY
    PackingStation
```

Expected result:

| Packing Station | PackDate | Shift | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 1180 |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 1 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 555 |
| Dip Line 2 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 0 |
| Dip Line 2 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 2 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 0 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 762 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 3 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 1005 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 1 | 1792 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 2 | 0 |
| Dip Line 4 | 09-20-2021 | 3 | 704 |

Instead I get the following output where it's missing rows that should be there from the template:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9cCr.png)

Another picture to explain what I'm trying to do (R is real data, T is the template table I'm trying to move data too):
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ok66D.png)

Comment: Without sample data, it is a little hard to guess at what is going on.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Put what is need to ask into your post, not just at a link.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: updated with extra info..

Comment: You're inner joining your tables - so you have only matching rows from both; you want all the rows from your BaseDipline table, so you need to outer-join.

Comment: @Stu I get the following when I change inner to outer: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'JOIN'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `outer join` condition. Your base table is the left input and you should `left join` to your second table:

```
select b.PackingStation, b.PackDate, b.[Shift], IsNull(s.Qty, b.Qty) Qty
from dbo.BaseDipline b
left join dbo.vwDipLinePackingActivity_Summary s
     on s.PackingStation=b.PackingStation
    and s.[shift]=b.[shift]
    and s.PackDate=@date
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Quick question, is there a way to modify this query so that for everything in the Shift column that = 2, a different variable is able to be used for the date?

Comment: Why did you leave off the schema for those objects? Schema-qualifying objects IS a best practice.

Comment: @Stu changed the last bit to this:

`and ((s.PackDate = @date and s.Shift in ('1', '3')) or (s.packDate = @previousDate and s.Shift = '2')) `

Comment: @SMor Yes you are correct - I only intended to leave off the unecessary database 3-part name; it's just the auto formatting of my local test environment, I have added the schema.

Comment: @alfonso2330 Yes, depending on your requirement you might want to use `isnull` for the date column like for the Qty column.